# mysql query with 2 innerjoins from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT name from login
(INNER JOIN connections on login.id = connections.receiver) AND (INNER JOIN connections on login.id = connections.sender)
WHERE (((connections.sender = '33') AND (connections.status = 'active'))
AND ((connections.receiver = '33') AND (connections.status = 'active')))
```

I am trying to get the names of all individuals who are sender if my session_id (33) is receiver and names of all receivers if my session_id is sender

How should this be done ?

Comment: session_id is not mentioned in the query you posted. Can you post the table structures?

Comment: Do you need an sql-only answer, or can you use a php script instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query shoud show the names and in which of the two scenarios the name was found.

```
select distinct name, status from (
  select name , 'Receiver' status
  from login, connections 
  where login.id = connections.receiver
  and connections.receiver = '33'
  and connections.status = 'active'
  union
  SELECT name , 'Sender' status
  from login, connections 
  where login.id = connections.sender
  and connections.sender= '33'
  and connections.status = 'active'
)
```

Comment: union of 2 queries worked very well. i almost forgot we could union 2 separate queries to form one. thanks Juan

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `IN()`

```
    SELECT `name` from login
    WHERE `login`.`id` IN (SELECT `sender` FROM `connections` WHERE `sender` = '33' AND `status` = 'active')
    OR `login`.`id` IN (SELECT `receiver` FROM `connections` WHERE `receiver` = '33' AND `status` = 'active')
```

Comment: i am sorry, i asked the question wrong, i wanted to get the names of sender if my session_id is receiver and get the names of receiver if my session_id is sender

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN connections on login.id = connections.receiver AND login.id = connections.sender
```

try it instead of this

```
(INNER JOIN connections on login.id = connections.receiver) AND (INNER JOIN connections on login.id = connections.sender)
```